# The HTML dfn and abbr tags and correct usage of the title attribute

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to use the `dfn` tag along with the `title` attribute and `abbr` tag I am not sure if I'm doing it correctly and was hoping if someone can tell me if any if not all of my examples below are correct or wrong if so which example(s) is wrong and why so I can have a better understanding of what I am doing and correct my error(s) Thanks?

Example 1

```
<p><dfn>CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

Example 2

```
<p><dfn title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

Example 3

```
<p><dfn title="A style sheet language used for describing the look and formatting of a document written in a markup language.">CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

Example 4

```
<p><dfn><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

Example 5

```
<p><dfn title="CSS"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be:

```
<p>
  <dfn>
    <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>
  </dfn>
  is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.
</p>
```

> Else, if it contains only an abbr element with a title attribute, then the term is the value of that attribute.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn)

Comment: Well, I would simply say they don't follow the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Although two of these examples are semantically correct, the most semantic way is *example 4*.**

```
<p><dfn>CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

> **Correct**. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn), because you are not using the `title` attribute, "CSS" is considered to be the term defined by the sentence within `p`.

```
<p><dfn title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

> **Incorrect**. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn), the `title` attribute is meant for "*another form of the term*", but only when the term defined isn't an abreviation. When the term is an abreviation, `abbr` should be used within the `dfn` element.

```
<p><dfn title="A style sheet language used for describing the look and formatting of a document written in a markup language.">CSS</dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

> **Incorrect**. The `title` attribute is meant for "*another form of the term*", not its definition.

```
<p><dfn><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

> **Correct**. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn), that's the recommended usage.

```
<p><dfn title="CSS"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dfn> is a simple mechanism for adding style to Web documents.</p>
```

> **Incorrect**. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn), if the `dfn` element contains a single child element and does not have any text content of its own, and the child element is an `abbr` element with a title attribute itself, then the exact value of the `abbr` element's `title` attribute is the term being defined. Therefore, the title attribute of the `dfn` element shouldn't be taken into account by semantic systems (A.I., lurkers, accessibility, etc.)

---

N.B. I produced this answer mostly leveraging the "*Using abbreviations and definitions together*" and "*Specifying the term being defined*" sections of the [dfn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn) on Mozilla

Comment: Can we use `<p><dfn><abbr title="Vegan">V</abbr> Vegan </dfn> <dfn><abbr title="Gluten Free">gf</abbr> Gluten Free</dfn></p>`. Thanks

Comment: Not quite. It always depends on what you are semantically trying to accomplish. I'm making a few guesses, but I believe the `<dfn>` tag doesn't semanticaly belong in this context. The following is correct: `<p><abbr title="Vegan">V</abbr> <abbr title="Gluten Free">gf</abbr></p>`

Comment: in your example, you totally omitted "Vegan" or "Gluten Free" I need to have the "Vegan" or "Gluten Free" in the content i.e shown along side `V` or `gf` and thats why I used `<dfn>`, how would you do it.

Comment: These requirements help! ;-) 
Because it doesn't include a definition for the words Vegan nor Gluten Free, but only abbreviation followed by the full word, I believe the most semantic way is: 
`<p><abbr title="Vegan">V</abbr> Vegan <abbr title="Gluten Free">gf</abbr> Gluten Free</p>` you could throw in two `span` for styling, but they add no semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They are all “correct” in the sense of matching the loose definitions of `abbr` and `dfn` in HTML specifications and drafts. The statement here is not really a definition at all (it says something about CSS, instead of specifying its essential features needed to distinguish it from other entities, and “CSS” is not really an abbreviation but name, though nominally formed as an abbreviation of some words. But the specs are so vague that even the markup in the question may well be interpreted as matching the “semantics” of these elements.

The question is rather academic, since `abbr` and `dfn` have almost no impact on anything but some features of default rendering, and you could and should use CSS rules that either confirm or override such styling, and then you might almost as well use `span`.